# Make only the top of an element clickable

Tags: jquery

I have an element where I want to only make the **80 first pixels clickable**. My html code is a bit weird because the content is reordered with css and flexbox so I can't add additional elements to make the first element clickable.

My html is :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I just want the 80 first pixel of every **li** be clickable. I can't attribute it to a div because in desktop I show all the div and in mobile I only show some and I change the order wih flexbox and order.
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: make a child element with specified height. then bind the click event to that element.

Comment: You could make a span within the div, and have a height of 80px. The click event could be attached to it. If the div is having some padding, make div as `position:relative`, and span to `position: absolute; top: 0px` so that it always sticks to the top.

Comment: I added the html and explanation, sorry for not putting it at the start. I can't put a div over another div because the div containt text who need to be selectable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can capture the click position, then compare it to the top offset of the element:

```
$('li').click(function (e) {
    var posY = $(this).offset().top;

    if (e.pageY - posY <= 80) {
        alert('Boom!');
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/hu3g574r/)**

[jQuery .offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) gets the distance to the edges of the page for a given element, and `top` is one of its available properties. [jQuery event.pageY](http://api.jquery.com/event.pagey/) gets the mouse position at the time of the click event.

Answer (score 4):

I'd do it by using `pointer-events` and `::before` pseudo-element. Example: http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/dYedMj

CSS:

```
div {
  height: 160px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

div::before {
  pointer-events: all;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$('div').on('click', function() {
  alert('clicked the top 80px');
});
```

Comment: True, I wasn't aware of bad IE support. Here's the correct link to caniuse: http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

Comment: This is clever use of pseudo element

Comment: Thanks, that do the job but I need something who is very supported because most of our customers use old browsers, I'll still save it because I didn't know about pointer-events !

Answer (score 0):

> Hope this is what you are looking for.

Changed the code according to your comment @kyll

```js
$('.parent').click(function(e){

if((e.clientX -$(this).offset().left) <= 80)
  alert('Click event fired');
})
```

```css
.parent{
  width:300px;
  height:40px;
  background:green;

  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using CSS pointer events to disable the main div but not a pseudo element.

`pointer-events` are now supported within all latest browser versions.

- [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  console.log('test');
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: green;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/sud40sb4/1/) example fiddle.

**CODE**

**HTML**

```
<div id="my_div">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/">
    <span id="clickable_span">
    </span>
  </a>
  <br>
  <span>
    The Battle of Concepción was fought on October 28, 1835, between Mexican troops and Texian insurgents on the grounds of Mission Concepción (pictured in 2010), 2 miles (3.2 km) south of what is now Downtown San Antonio in the U.S. state of Texas.
  </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#clickable_span {
    height: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
#my_div {
    height: 1000px;
}
```